# Responsive Slider Background Image Stretch

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Am trying to use a slider which can be responsive. When i resize the screen to tablet or mobile size. I am getting a weird margin at the top and bottom.

I am not able to override the margin via inline css as well.

[Test Link](http://play.mink7.com/soull/html/soull/index.html)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Firstly, Use `background-size: cover;` for `.fullwidthbanner-container` Secondly, adjust your slider `<img />`s that are *absolutely* positioned and images are set by not by pixels, but by percentages.

Comment: Right, your inline CSS will not affect because your inline css is hard coded but library also appending inline css dynamically.

Comment: Please use anyother responsive slider OR you can customize your library